# How to detect if iOS Keychain items not available yet? (before first unlock)

Tags: ios, security, keychain

Is there a specific error or behavior exhibited when `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` items are accessed in the background **before** the device is unlocked?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlock?language=objc

Apple states:

> This is recommended for items that need to be accessed by background
>   applications.

However, there are circumstances when apps can still be launched by the system before this occurs, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know "Error Code **-25308** (errSecInteractionNotAllowed)" is returned, but I haven't been able to verify yet.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1542001-security_framework_result_codes/errsecinteractionnotallowed?language=objc